# why the result is different?? JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JavaScript these days,
I write this simple code in different ways but the result is different!
in test paragraph, it gives me an undefined value at the end!
so what is the difference between test and test 2?

```js
// test

let newNumbers = [1 , 5 , 43 , 96 , 100 , 201];
let text = "";
newNumbers.forEach(iterationMethod);

function iterationMethod( value , index , array) {
    text = text + value + "<br>";
    return text
}

document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = iterationMethod();

// test 2 

let newNumbers2 = [1 , 5 , 43 , 96 , 100 , 201];
let text2 = "";
newNumbers2.forEach(iterationMethod2);

function iterationMethod2( value , index , array) {
    text2 = text2 + value + "<br>";
}

document.getElementById('test2').innerHTML = text2;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>JS - Test</title>
</head>

<body>

    <p id="test"></p>
 
    <br><h2>TEST 2</h2><br>
    
    <p id="test2"></p>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why is the function for iteration being reused like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `iterationMethod()` at the end of
`document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = iterationMethod();`
it invokes the function another time but without any arguments, so it appends 'undefined' to text.

Here, this might help illustrate:

```
// test

let newNumbers = [1 , 5 , 43 , 96 , 100 , 201];
let text = "";
newNumbers.forEach(iterationMethod);

function iterationMethod( value , index , array) {

    text = text + value + "<br>";
    return text;
    
}
iterationMethod();
iterationMethod();
iterationMethod();

document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = iterationMethod();
```

This gives an output like:

```
1
5
43
96
100
201
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

There are 4 'undefined' in `text` because now it's calling `iterationMethod()` 4 times without any arguments.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are calling `iterationMethod()` without any arguments, which translates to `iterationMethod(undefined, undefined, undefined)`

Comment: Yes, but confusingly it returns the value of `text` which will be correct.

Comment: By the time the function is called without any arguments, the foreach loop is already performed, so it just appends undefined at the end and returns the text value.

Answer (score 0):

foreach doesn't return anything, it just provides a way to iterate through an array and do things.
[see this link for learn more (return value is undifind)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line during first test:

```
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = iterationMethod();
```

Here you're executing `iterationMethod` a sevent'th time with no arguments.
During this call the `value` parameter is undefined and so the value 'undefined' is appended to the value of `text`

It work's as expected if you write this:

```
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = text;
```

Answer (score -1):

You are calling `iterationMethod` twice, and the second time it is called you're not passing any arguments, and it's not inside a `forEach` statement, so it's undefined

```js
// test

let newNumbers = [1 , 5 , 43 , 96 , 100 , 201];
let text = "";
newNumbers.forEach(iterationMethod); // < HERE

function iterationMethod( value , index , array) {
    text = text + value + "<br>";
    return text
}

document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = iterationMethod(); // < HERE
```